# Find length, width and height of a cuboid

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Consider a cuboid (that is, a rectangular box / rectangular parallelepiped) with the following properties:

- the area of its top face is $240$ cm$^2$
- the area of its front face is $300$ cm$^2$
- the area of its face on the righthand side is $180$ cm$^2$

Determine the three edge lengths (length, width, height) of the cuboid from this information.

Comment: If it's a cube, all the faces should have the same area. It's not really clear what you mean by "upper area," "front Area," and "bottom Area".

Comment: its not need no be square cube, it can be cuboid

Comment: @Arash, a cube is "[A symmetrical three-dimensional shape, either solid or hollow, contained by six ***equal squares***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cube)". If the sides aren't square then it isn't a cube, it's a cuboid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be moved to math.SE. It is a totally standard algebraic problem.

Answer (score 7):

$x * y = 240 \text{ cm²}$

$y * z = 300 \text{ cm²}$

$x * z = 180 \text{ cm²}$

Solve for x gives: $x * x = \frac{240 * 180}{300} = 144 \text{ cm²}$

Which gives:

$x = 12 \text{ cm}$

$y = 20 \text{ cm}$

$z = 15 \text{ cm}$

Answer (score 4):

A rectangular block of width $a$, height $b$, and depth $c$ has front area $ab=300$, top area $ac=240$, and side area $bc=180$. So we have:

$a^2=\frac{ab \times ac}{bc}=\frac{300 \times 240}{180}=400$ $\rightarrow$ $a=20$.

$b^2=\frac{ab \times bc}{ac}=\frac{300 \times 180}{240}=225$ $\rightarrow$ $b=15$.

$c^2=\frac{ac \times bc}{ab}=\frac{240 \times 180}{300}=144$ $\rightarrow$ $c=12$.

Answer (score 4):

1. Multiply them all together and take the square root:

$$
abc = \sqrt{a^2b^2c^2} = \sqrt{ab * ac * bc} = \sqrt{12960000} = 3600
$$

2. Divide by the missing term to get each side:

$$
a = \frac{3600}{bc} = \frac{3600}{240} = 15 \\
b = \frac{3600}{ac} = \frac{3600}{300} = 12 \\
c = \frac{3600}{ab} = \frac{3600}{180} = 20
$$

Answer (score 3):

First, I have to translate this into a valid question.

1. It's not a cube; it's a rectangular prism.
2. There aren't upper, front, and bottom areas; there are top, front, and side areas.

Starting from that point, we can work through the following:

- A rectangular prism has 3 dimensions: height, width, depth
- The top face's area = width * depth
- The front face's area = width * height
- The side face's area = height * depth
- Let's simplify these equations into `t=w*d`, `f=w*h`, and `s=h*d`
- Solve for `w=t/d` and plug that into `f=w*h` to get `f=(t/d)*h`
- Solve for `h=f*d/t` and plug that into `s=h*d` to get `s=(f*d/t)*d`
- Solve `d^2=s*t/f`
- `s`, `t`, and `f` are given in the problem as 180 cm^2, 240 cm^2, and 300 cm^2, respectively
- Plug those in to get `d^2=180*240/300` or `d^2=144` or `d=12`
- Work backwards through the functions to get `h=15` and `w=20`

So the height is 15 cm, the width is 20 cm, and the depth (or length) is 12 cm.
I believe my correction to the question is valid as the answer came out to simple integers.